# Spring integration connecting inbound HTTP gateway with outbound Websocket gateaway

Tags: spring-integration, spring-websocket

I want to create a REST service to turn on the light. The architecture that I want to have is the following:

- Many embedded system each is connected to one light instance
- Each embedded system has a websocket client, that connects to my server
- My server holds a REST service that allows webclients to choose one light instance, and turn it on
- The REST service would have a parameter to specify a reference for one light instance, connected to the system and send the message to websocket client, wait for an acknowledgement message from the client, and return the REST answer

I would like to accomplish this using Spring Integration framework. I was thinking of something like:

Request : Inbound HTTP GW -> Outbound Websocket GW

Response: Inbound HTTP GW <- Inbound Websocket GW

The problem is that I don't know how to specify the websocket client. Any idea how to do it ?

For now, and based on the answers I have received this is the pseudo-code that provides the solution:

```
<!-- REST service to turn on the light -->    
<int-http:inbound-gateway
        supported-methods="POST"
        request-channel="lightOnRequest"
        reply-channel="lightOnResponse"
        path="rest/lighton/{sessionId}">
    <int-http:header name="{sessionId}" expression="{sessionId}"/>
</int-http:inbound-gateway>

<!-- We add a header SESSION_ID_HEADER to choose the websocket destination client -->
<int:header-enricher 
    input-channel="lightOnRequest" 
    output-channel="lightOnClientRequest">
    <int:header 
        name="#{T(...SimpMessageHeaderAccessor).SESSION_ID_HEADER}"
        expression="headers.sessionId"/>
    <int:header-channels-to-string/>
</int:header-enricher>

<!-- Websocket out to client -->
<int-websocket:outbound-channel-adapter 
    channel="lightOnClientRequest" 
    container="serverWebSocketContainer" />

<!-- Response reception from the Websocket client -->
<int-websocket:inbound-channel-adapter 
    channel="lightOnClientResponse" 
    container="serverWebSocketContainer" />

<!-- The websocket client provides again the reply channel in the headers.
     The bridge connects the response to the reply channel -->
<int:bridge input-channel="lightOnClientResponse"/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, your question isn't clear. If your WebSocket stuff is based on the Spring Integration WEbSocket adapters, you have `ServerWebSocketContainer` which has `getSessions()` to return `Map<String, WebSocketSession>` of connected client sessions. Hence you can expose to end-users via REST service.

When the client select one session and send an HTTP request you can simply forward that message with the `SimpMessageHeaderAccessor.SESSION_ID_HEADER` to the `<int-websocket:outbound-channel-adapter>`.

And yes, you can receive an acknowledgement using `<int-websocket:inbound-channel-adapter>` and forward it to the REST response automatically. But to achieve that you should convert `TemporaryReplyChannel` from the `<int-http:inbound-gateway>` to `String` using `<header-channels-to-string>` on `<header-enricher>`.

You Client WebSocket application must ensure to return those request headers with the `replyChannel`, when it send acknowledgement to the session. With Spring Integration on that side everything should be transparent.

Let me know if I have missed something.

**UPDATE**

Good. Thanks for more info!  Your config looks good. Some remarks: 1. No need to have `reply-channel="lightOnResponse"`: HTTP Inbound Gateway waits for the reply from the `TemporaryReplyChannel` very well. 2. Please, add `<header-channels-to-string>` to your `<header-enricher>` before forwarding to the WebSocket. 3. The `<int-websocket:inbound-channel-adapter>` can just sends its inbound message to the simple `bridge`: `<bridge input-channel="lightOnClientResponse">`. In this case without `output-channel` it delegate message to the `replyChannel` from headers. Hence your HTTP Inbound Gateway will receive appropriate reply.

Comment: Hi Artem. Thanks for your reply. All my development is based on Spring Integration, which means yes the Websocket stuff is based on Spring Integration Adapters. I understand now from your reply how to choose the websocket client (based on the SESSION_ID_HEADER), and I will be able to forward to correct client. But I don't understand, how I can forward the websocket response automatically as a REST response. I will send a piece of code below hoping you could comment again.